# Converting JSON pretty print to one line

Tags: json, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a command that I run and it gives an output like below:

```
{
"endpointApplications": {
    "App_Name": {
        "connectionState": "Disconnected",
        "connectionTime": "No connection was established",
        "linkAttributes": {
            "ackSettings": {
                "dataAckEnabled": "true",
                "dataAckTimeout": "5000",
                "dataNakRetryLimit": "0",
                "retransmitDelay": "500"
            },
            "keepAliveSettings": {
                "keepAliveAckTimeout": "5000",
                "keepAliveInterval": "30000"
            },
            "logTraffic": "false",
            "port": "9999",
            "role": "server"
        },
        "protocol": "snmp"
    }
},
"queueStats": {}
}
```

I would need the output to be in one line like below:

```
{"endpointApplications": {"app_name": {"connectionState": "Disconnected","connectionTime": "No connection was established","linkAttributes": {"ackSettings":{"dataAckEnabled": "true","dataAckTimeout": "5000","dataNakRetryLimit": "0","retransmitDelay": "500"},"keepAliveSettings":{"keepAliveAckTimeout": "5000","keepAliveInterval": "30000"},"logTraffic": "false","port": "9999","role": "server"},"protocol": "snmp"}},"queueStats":{}}
```

I tried using awk and sed combining different parameters but I can't get to work without losing the JSON format.

Comment: Consider using `jq` for whatever you appear to be trying to do to each resulting line :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`jq` or any other `json` aware tool is best suited for json file manipulation.However here is `awk` based solution.

```
awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1' input.json
{ "endpointApplications": { "App_Name": { "connectionState": "Disconnected", "connectionTime": "No connection was established", "linkAttributes": { "ackSettings": { "dataAckEnabled": "true", "dataAckTimeout": "5000", "dataNakRetryLimit": "0", "retransmitDelay": "500" }, "keepAliveSettings": { "keepAliveAckTimeout": "5000", "keepAliveInterval": "30000" }, "logTraffic": "false", "port": "9999", "role": "server" }, "protocol": "snmp" } }, "queueStats": {} }
```

Note: This solution is mainly for the legacy systems not having tools like `jq` and have no chance to get them installed due to some reasons.

Comment: can you please help me further by explaining awk action part `{$1=$1}1` a bit.  I wrote my own something like `awk -v ORS= '{ print $0 } END { printf "\n" }'`  but yours is far better!!

Comment: `{$1=$1}1` is a famous construct in awk world. This is done to force/fake awk to reconstruct the record using the value of `RS` we passed. Without the reconstruction of the record the value we passed for RS won't show up in the results. Btw you can use anything for reconstruction of the record like `$8=$8`. The last 1, is to force the conditions to be true for printing.

Comment: Also, to make more sense , in awk by default a record is equal to a line. Eg speerated by new line.

Answer (score 43):

You should use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for stuff like that:

```
jq -c . input.txt
```

An alternative quick a dirty solution would be to use `sed` & `tr`:

```
sed -e 's/^ *//' < input.txt | tr -d '\n'
```

although I would recommend using `jq` which is designed for manipulating JSON. `jq` is like `sed` for JSON. Manipulating JSON textually with `sed`/`awk`/etc is not guaranteed to produce semantically equivalent JSON.

Comment: You can obtain `jq` under a Debian-flavored Linux (such as Ubuntu) with a simple `sudo apt-get install jq`

Comment: Alternative solution worked for me, because I managed json data from mongodb, that contains special datatypes