# Flatten JSON document to single line

Tags: python, arrays, json, regex, parsing

**Context:** An API I'm integrating spits out data in pretty print form like below. I have a MSSQL parsing proc that requires the input JSON to have a flat form in a single line (tabs removed).

**Question:**
I've found some semi-related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648222/converting-json-pretty-print-to-one-line) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976488/filtering-json-from-api-through-jq-in-python) but they dont seem to address my needs because I dont want to perform operations on the file level.

Can anyone recommend some specific methods for transforming the JSON text into a single line in a more granular fashion? Perhaps regular expressions or some string manipulation methods?

**Current JSON form:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "first_name": "Eric",
    "last_name": "B",
    "email": null,
    "score": null,
    "domain": "@datashiftlabs.io",
    "position": null,
    "twitter": null,
    "linkedin_url": null,
    "phone_number": null,
    "company": null,
    "sources": []
  },
  "meta": {
    "params": {
      "first_name": "Eric",
      "last_name": "B",
      "full_name": null,
      "domain": "@datashiftlabs.io",
      "company": null
    }
  }
}
```

**Desired form:**

```
{"data": {"first_name": "Eric","last_name": "B","email": null,"score": null,"domain": "datashiftlabs.io","position": null,"twitter": null,"linkedin_url": null,"phone_number": null,"company": null,"sources": []},"meta": {"params": {"first_name": "Eric","last_name": "B","full_name": null,"domain": "datashiftlabs.io","company": null}}}
```

Comment: Why can't full file work? from your example it looks like it's flattening the whole input file.

Comment: Again, the MSSQL proc depends on a specific structure and the added tabs malform the needed structure & prevent the parsing from executing properly.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the statement "I don't want to do preform operations on the file level" to mean you only wanted to act on a subset of lines in a file. :/

Comment: Your "MSSQL proc" seems to be rubbish. A tool that does not comply with file standards properly has the potential to have other troubles. Crafted malicious data might allow things like second level injections into the database. In other words: your problem is that tool, not the JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's actually what you want, but you could convert your json string with the `json` library to an object, and than convert it back to a string.

The example would look like this

```
import json

json_str = """{
  "data": {
    "first_name": "Eric",
    "last_name": "B",
    "email": null,
    "score": null,
    "domain": "@datashiftlabs.io",
    "position": null,
    "twitter": null,
    "linkedin_url": null,
    "phone_number": null,
    "company": null,
    "sources": []
  },
  "meta": {
    "params": {
      "first_name": "Eric",
      "last_name": "B",
      "full_name": null,
      "domain": "@datashiftlabs.io",
      "company": null
    }
  }
}"""

obj = json.loads(json_str)
flatten_str = json.dumps(obj)

print(flatten_str)
```

An alternativ would be using string replace and regex substitution to remove all unnecessary characters like line-breaks, multiple spaces and tabs. A quick draft for this function would look like this.
***Note**: The current regex does not work flawlessly and still has some unintended behavior on certain edge cases, e.g. multiple whitespaces at the end of a string*

```
import re

def flatten_json(string):
    # Remove line breaks
    string = string.replace("\n", "")
    # Remove tabs and multiple spaces
    string = re.sub('[\t ]+("|{|})', r' \1', string)
    # Return result
    return string
```

Comment: The first approach is solid. The second one is better than I expected it to be, but not perfect; consider `[<spaces>[<spaces>"hello"<spaces>]<spaces>]` -- I have some of those multi-space regions surviving. Not sure there aren't other cases it breaks I haven't yet discovered, either.

Comment: Also (in the second approach only), spaces are collapsed inside quoted strings in some cases, when those quoted strings also contain curly braces as literal values with adjacent runs of spaces.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're absolutly right, the second option might make some mistakes by either removing important whitespaces inside a string or keeping superfluous whitespaces, thats why i said, its just a quick draft. The regex would need to be improved by quite a bit before actually working flawless.

Comment: *nod*. I'd suggest calling out the risk of semantic changes explicitly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i've added a quick disclaimer for possible problems with the current regex